# Criteria Builder Query generating normal join rather than left join in where clause

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, orm, hibernate-criteria

Am trying to fetch data using Criteria Builder .
But query is getting generated with two more joins which should have been covered in left join.

## Please check my code below.

```
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManagerRead.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ClientPostedJobDataResponse> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ClientPostedJobDataResponse.class);
        Root<ClientPostedJobData> root = criteriaQuery.from(ClientPostedJobData.class);

        Specification<ClientPostedJobData> dataSpecification = ClientPostedJobsDataSpecificationBuilder.specificationBuilder(request);
        Predicate predicate = dataSpecification.toPredicate(root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder);
        if (predicate != null)
            criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

        Join<Object, Object> user = root.join("clientId", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Object, Object> clientProposalList = root.join("freelancerProposalList", JoinType.LEFT);

        criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("jobId"), root.get("jobName"), user.get("userId"), root.get("message"),
                root.get("offeredAmount"),
                criteriaBuilder.function("DATE_FORMAT", LocalDate.class, root.get("createdOn")
                        , criteriaBuilder.literal("%Y-%m-%d"))
                , root.get("expiredOn"), root.get("active"),
                criteriaBuilder.coalesce(criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(clientProposalList.get("id")), 0));

        criteriaQuery.orderBy(Sort.Direction.ASC.equals(request.getDirection()) ? criteriaBuilder.asc(
                root.get(request.getOrderBy())) : criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(request.getOrderBy())));
        criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get("jobId"));

        TypedQuery<ClientPostedJobDataResponse> query = entityManagerRead.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        List<ClientPostedJobDataResponse> response = query.setFirstResult(request.getOffSet()).setMaxResults(
                request.getLimit()).getResultList();
        log.info("fetched jobs :{}", response.size());
        long recordCount = response.size() < request.getLimit() ? request.getOffSet() +
                response.size() : clientPostedJobDataRepo.count(dataSpecification);
```

## Now below is my Specification code :

```
public class ClientPostedJobsDataSpecificationBuilder {

    private ClientPostedJobsDataSpecificationBuilder() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Client Posted Specification class cannot be initialized.");
    }

    public static Specification<ClientPostedJobData> specificationBuilder(ClientPostedJobsDataSearchRequest request) {
        List<Specification<ClientPostedJobData>> specifications = new ArrayList<>();
        specifications.add(Specification.where(fetchJoinEntities()));

        if (GeneralUtils.isNotNull(request.getJobId()))
            specifications.add((root, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("jobId"), request.getJobId()));

        if (GeneralUtils.isNotNull(request.getClientId()))
            specifications.add((root, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("clientId").get("userId"), request.getClientId()));

        if (GeneralUtils.isNotNull(request.getExpiredOn()))
            specifications.add((root, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("expiredOn"), request.getExpiredOn()));

        if (GeneralUtils.isNotNull(request.getOfferedAmount()))
            specifications.add((root, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("offeredAmount"), request.getOfferedAmount()));

        if (GeneralUtils.isNotNull(request.getActive()))
            specifications.add((root, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("active"), request.getActive()));

        if (GeneralUtils.isNotNull(request.getUserId()))
            specifications.add((root, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get("freelancerProposalList").get("freelancerUserId").get("userId"),
                    request.getUserId()));

        return Specifications.combineWithAnd(specifications);
    }

    private static Specification<ClientPostedJobData> fetchJoinEntities() {
        return (root, cq, cb) -> {
            if (ClientPostedJobData.class == cq.getResultType()) {
                cq.distinct(true);
                root.fetch("clientId", JoinType.LEFT);
                Fetch<Object, Object> freelancerProposal = root.fetch("freelancerProposalList", JoinType.LEFT);
                freelancerProposal.fetch("freelancerUserId", JoinType.LEFT);
            }
            return cb.conjunction();
        };
    }
}
```

## Query Getting generated for this :

```
  select
        c1_0.job_id,
        c1_0.job_name,
        c2_0.user_id,
        c1_0.message,
        c1_0.offered_amount,
        DATE_FORMAT(c1_0.created_on,'%Y-%m-%d'),
        c1_0.expired_on,
        c1_0.active,
        coalesce(count(distinct f1_0.id),0) 
    from
        posted_job_data c1_0 
    left join
        user c2_0 
            on c2_0.id=c1_0.client_id 
    left join
        client_proposal f1_0 
            on c1_0.id=f1_0.posted_job_id 
            and (
                f1_0.deleted = 0
            )  
    join
        client_proposal f2_0 
            on c1_0.id=f2_0.posted_job_id 
    join
        user f3_0 
            on f3_0.id=f2_0.freelancer_user_id 
    where
        (
            c1_0.deleted=0
        ) 
        and 1=1 
        and f3_0.user_id='OWN473329FJU'
    group by
        1 
    order by
        c1_0.id desc limit 0,
        100
```

I have tried checking on internet and lots of debugging by myself , but tuck on it for more than three days.

Comment: "two more joins which should have been covered in left join", actually they should not. `freelancerProposal.fetch("freelancerUserId", JoinType.LEFT)` - you are asking HBN to add extra join in order to return extra data within single query, `cb.equal(root.get("freelancerProposalList").get("freelancerUserId").get("userId"))` - is just a filter, i.e. "return job postings where particular user was somehow participating"

Comment: but should not they have been left join rather than join ?